# How to paint arc or moon shape over another circle in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I really need your help to create or paint this kind of container in a flutter,

**What I Want is below pic as a result**

[image]

this is to show user profiles or different users inside this container like this, please help me out with how to do this I would really like you to appreciate your help, thanks in advance

**What I did so far:**

```
 Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    begin: Alignment.topRight,
                                    end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                    colors: [
                                      Color(0XFF8134AF),
                                      Color(0XFFDD2A7B),
                                      Color(0XFFFEDA77),
                                      Color(0XFFF58529),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle),
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage(
                                      IconAssets.user_icon,
                                    ),
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(AppMargin.m2),
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(AppPadding.p3),
                              ),
                            ),
```

**Result:**

[image]

**please help me out how to create like above picture , thank you**

Comment: you need a `CustomPaint` widget for such shapes

Comment: yes, I know but I could not create this shape in CustomPaint,  Could you pls help create this shape?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/arcToPoint.html you need to call it twice, first with radius r0 and second with bigger radius r1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using `PathOperation.difference` to paint the moon.

```dart
class MoonPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    final paint = Paint()
      ..shader = const LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topRight,
        end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        colors: [
          Color(0XFF8134AF),
          Color(0XFFDD2A7B),
          Color(0XFFFEDA77),
          Color(0XFFF58529),
        ],
      ).createShader(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, size.width, size.height));

    Path path1 = Path()
      ..addOval(Rect.fromCenter(
          center: center, width: size.width, height: size.height));

    Path path2 = Path()
      ..addOval(
        Rect.fromCenter(
          center: Offset(
            center.dx - 10,
            center.dy - 10,
          ),
          width: size.width - 10,
          height: size.height - 10,
        ),
      );
    canvas.drawPath(
      Path.combine(PathOperation.difference, path1, path2),
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

[image]

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: 300,
  height: 300,
  child: CustomPaint(
    painter: MoonPainter(),
  ),
),
```

You can include another oval inside paint. Change the color and decorate the way you like

Comment: all you need is `arcToPoint` method called twice - that gives you a full control wher you want to draw the 'moon'

Comment: @pskink  I've  tried, but failed to do, I will try once more.

Comment: Path()..move to(p0.dx, p0.dy)..arcToPoint(p1, radius: 200)..arcToPoint(p0, radius: 300, clockwise: false)

Comment: this is more or less pseudocode - radius should be rather Radius.circular(nnn) - I write it from my phone - that's why I used 200 or 300 for short

Comment: Thanks, I will try after the sdk upgrade

Comment: thank a lot @YeasinSheikh it was a great help

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
child: Container(
          width: 400,
          height: 400,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topRight,
                end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                colors: [
                  Color(0XFF8134AF),
                  Color(0XFFDD2A7B),
                  Color(0XFFFEDA77),
                  Color(0XFFF58529),
                ],
              ),
              shape: BoxShape.circle),
          child: Align(
            child: Container(
              width: 350,
              height: 350,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Comment: No, the above-given shape I want, it has a circle with an image inside it then two arcs with the different colors green and blue over the first circle

Comment: like this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxGYs.png

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a basic idea of how you can draw an arc using paint and place it over another widget.

https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id=0cc9f5ad27e13bc76b8cee125dabfd71